# jQuery fading two images without white

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I would like to fade image without white transfer between them.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <span><img src="1.jpg"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.image > span > img').fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $('.image > span > img').attr('src', images[i]);
  $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

This works, but there is white fade between changing. Images array contains image sources.
I found this http://jsfiddle.net/byB6L/ but I can not update my code to work with that.

Comment: Put your images into a div with the background color that you want.

Comment: @kraYz I do not want any colors changing between images. Changing them like top of each other.

Comment: @kraYz that's absolutely **not** the way to go, but symultaneously fade 2 images

Comment: @user2086252 there's lot of similar questions already answered (by me too) here on SO. take a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your using the same image on the animation end callback.

My suggestion: use `position: relative;` on the `class="image"` container, put the image element as `position:absolute;`, now after you are fading the image out insert a new image into the container and fade it in and remove the first image.

Example:

Html:

```
<div class="image">
  <span><img src="1.jpg"></span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .image{position:relative;}
    .image span img{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
</style>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.image > span > img').fadeOut(1000);
    var $image = $('<img alt="" src="YOUR NEW IMAGE_PATH" style="opacity:0;" />');
    $('.image > span').append($image);
    $image.fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $('.image > span > img').first().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should give you an idea:

```js
var c = 0,                  // Counter index
    $img = $('.image img'), // Get images
    n = $img.length;        // How many images?

$img.eq(c).show();          // Show c one

(function loop() {          // Recursive infinite loop
    $img.delay(1000).fadeOut(800).eq(++c%n).fadeIn(800, loop);
}());
```

```css
.image{
  position:relative;
}
.image img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px; 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/bf0?text=Apples" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/0bf?text=and" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/fb0?text=Pears" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fading out one image and then fading in another, use two image elements and layer them on top of each other, then just fade out the top one to make the bottom one appear instead.

CSS:

```
.image img { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <img class="bottomImage" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"/>
  <img class="topImage" src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.topImage').fadeOut(3000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/grTUK/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery doesn't support background image animations like background color animation(which is also need to use extra plugin). So to do your animation, definitely you need to have two images.

Comment: (offtopic) I'm truly sorry if you found my comments offensive, It was not my intention but to give some suggestions for maybe an answer improvement. I'll work on my ethics. Happy coding