# Change SVG stroke on path with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, stroke

I've set my SVG image as the background of a div. Now I want to change the stroke of a specific path with jQuery every x seconds. I've seen an example ([click me](http://bl.ocks.org/widged/4545199)) where this is basically done.

This is my jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var _currStroke = 'ffa500';

  var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M69.527,2H29.971L2,29.971v39.558L29.971,97.5h39.558L97.5,69.527V29.972L69.527,2z M95.625,68.898L68.898,95.625H31.101  L4.375,68.898V31.516v-0.414L31.102,4.375h37.796l26.728,26.727L95.625,68.898L95.625,68.898z"/> <path d="M68.07,6.375H31.93L6.375,31.93v36.142L31.93,93.626h36.142L93.625,68.07V31.93L68.07,6.375z" id="outline_path" style="stroke:'+_currStroke+'; transition: stroke .4s ease; opacity: 0.5" /> </svg>';

  var encoded = window.btoa(svg);
  $("nav").css("background", "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encoded+")");

  /* change stroke color every x seconds (atm: 3) */
  var changingTimeInMS = 3000;
  var currentColor = $("outline_path").attr('stroke');
  setInterval(function() {    

    var lastIndex = changeStrokeColor(currentColor, lastIndex);

  }, changingTimeInMS);

});

function changeStrokeColor(currentColor, lastIndex) {

    var colors = ['32cd32',  /* limegreen */
                '00ffff',  /* cyan */
                'ffa500',  /* orange */
                'ffffff']; /* white */

    $.each(colors, function(lastIndex) {
      if(colors[lastIndex] == currentColor) {
          return true;
      }
      $("#outline_path").attr('style', "stroke:'+this+'");
      $("#nav").css('border-color', this);

      lastIndex++;
      return lastIndex;
});

}
```

So let's go through it real quick:

1. I defined a stroke color to start with (_currStroke = 'ffa500')
2. I encode the svg and set it as the background of my nav
3. Please notice the svg path: it has an id (#'outline_path') and a styling: `style="stroke:'+_currStroke+'; transition: stroke .4s ease; opacity: 0.5"`
4. Save the current stroke color in a variable (currentColor)
5. call changeStrokeColor-function every `changeTimeInMS` - seconds
6. save the return value of changeStrokeColor in a variable (lastIndex)
7. changeStrokeColors expects two variables: the current color of the stroke and the last index (is the first call of changeStrokeColors even possible? lastIndex is not declared yet but I can't set it to 0 for example because then it would be resetted every x seconds)
8. Iterate through the colors-array; if the currentColor is equal to the index we are at the moment, skip it (`return true`) and continue with:
9. search for the path with the id `outline_path` and change the stroke to the element we are at right now in our iteration
10. Also change the nav border color to that color
11. increment lastIndex and return it

I can change the color with changing var _currStroke but the 'do-it-every-x-seconds'-thing is not working at all. Please note that I'm a beginner in JS (and SVGs). Any help is appreciated.

I made a CodePen to illustrate: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sqe/pen/DFqly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working live demo](http://jsbin.com/cazeqa/3/edit)**

So many issues in your code,
I'll *try* to cover them all:

1. You use a HTML element `<nav>` but in your code **you're trying to
   target some ID**: `$("#nav").css(` The right selector you want is
   actually the one you already used in your code, and that's
   `$("nav")`
2. You're **converting** your SVG element **to base64
   *data-image***.
   Once it's converted to image it's no more a *living* Object** you can manipulate, so basically you'll need to re-build a new image with different colors before using it.
   Otherwise you can explore how to use [SVG `<pattern>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Patterns).
3. You're setting **invalid colors** in your array `'32cd32'` **is not a HEX
   color**, while `'#32cd32'` is.
4. `$("outline_path")` **is not an ID selector** <sup>*see•1*</sup>, but in any case it's too late to
   target it cause your SVG is now a base64 data image
   <sup>*see•2*</sup>.
5. There's no need to remember the `lastIndex` color and iterate all over again your colors Array inside `$.each`, simply use an Array Counter pointer, increate that counter instead and use the *Reminder Operator %* against the total number of colors to loop your incremented Counter: `++counter%totColors`
6. `.attr('style', "stroke:'+this+'")` **is incorrect string** + var concatenation. Should be like: `.attr('style', "stroke:'"+ this +"'")` where all inside the doubles is string, and outside are `+` concatenated variables.
7. You'll need to pre-create all your images, to prevent blank gaps (image being created) once the interval starts ticking.
8. You'll not be able to set `transition: stroke .4s ease;` to an image. Sorry. You might want to explore some other tricks in fading a bg image (2 elements involved). [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270938/383904) [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975277/383904) [example3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213619/383904)
9. Don't recreate your variables all over again inside an interval. Make them Global instead.
10. Create a function that will return the new image.

Here's my attempt to rebuild it all following your idea and initial code:

```
var $nav = $("nav"), // Cache your selectors
  colors = [
  '#00ffff',  // cyan
  '#32cd32',  // limegreen
  '#ffa500',  // orange
  '#ffffff',  // white
  'red'
  ], 
  totColors = colors.length, // How many colors?
  counter = 0;               // Colors Array loop counter

function newSvg(co){
  var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  x="0px" y="0px" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M69.527,2H29.971L2,29.971v39.558L29.971,97.5h39.558L97.5,69.527V29.972L69.527,2z M95.625,68.898L68.898,95.625H31.101  L4.375,68.898V31.516v-0.414L31.102,4.375h37.796l26.728,26.727L95.625,68.898L95.625,68.898z"/> <path d="M68.07,6.375H31.93L6.375,31.93v36.142L31.93,93.626h36.142L93.625,68.07V31.93L68.07,6.375z" id="outline_path" style="stroke:'+ co +'; opacity: 0.5" /> </svg>';
  return "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+ window.btoa(svg);
}

function changeStrokeColor() {
  var co = colors[++counter%totColors]; // Increase and Loop colors
  $nav.css({
    borderColor: co,
    background : "url("+ newSvg(co) +")"
  });
}  

for(var i=0; i<totColors; i++){ // Preload all backgrounds
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = newSvg(colors[i]);
}

$(function(){ // DOM ready
  $nav.css("background", "url("+ newSvg( colors[counter] ) +")" );
  setInterval(changeStrokeColor, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I think I'll gonna spend some time reading the manual. What about performance now? Won't recreating an image all over again slow down the page?

Comment: @sqe no, the images, once created with `new Image` are pulled from the Browser cache. In any case I'd go exploring `<pattern>` that way you'll be able to do more cool stuff, not only apply the fade fx.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @sqe You're welcome. SVG are a bit complicated with all those properties, attributes... like a world on their own, but once you master them... :) *“In a dark place we find ourselves, and a little more knowledge lights our way.”* -Yoda